# The system cannot find the file specified windows error python

Tags: python, file, path, find, rename

I want to rename all the files in test folder as 1, 2, 3 and so on

```
import os, sys, path

path = r"F:\test"
dirs = os.listdir(path)

print(dirs)
count = 1
for files in dirs:
    str1 = str(count)
    os.rename(files, str1)
    count += 1
```

but my code giving me this error:
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dirs` is a list of paths, and iterating through it won't give you the contents of the directories. You would need another `os.listdir` for that.

Also, to rename the files, you have to go through each of them.

A better solution would've been:

```
import os

count = 1
path = r"F:\test"
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for filename in files:
        os.rename(os.path.join(root, filename), os.path.join(root, str(count)))
        count += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add one line to change bthe current working directory.

```
import os, sys, path

path = r"F:\test"
dirs = os.listdir(path)

os.chdir(path)  # Change the current working directory
print(dirs)
count = 1
for files in dirs:
    str1 = str(count)
    os.rename(files, str1)
    count += 1
```